# Running Greasemonkey javascript only after page JS changes content?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, onload

On some websites, HTML tags load after certain events occur (javascript function loading a query or search, or user needs to scroll down).

When writing your own javascript functions to try to edit these tags via `window.onload`, since the tags technically don't exist yet, the function does nothing. Placing the functions at the bottom of the body doesn't work, since those tags do not load after waiting a bit of time, but after their associated javascript functions create them.

For example, if you wanted to change the grey-black colour of the divs in *Google Images* after a search (which loads more pictures as you scroll down, but doesn't do anything if you don't), even you attempt to write a Greasemonkey script to perform actions with `window.onload`, it would not do anything after scrolling down since it's already loaded.

Would a possible (but crude) solution be to re-run the function each time the user scrolls down (like a mouse listener of sorts)? Or would you recommend another method? Just delaying the function doesn't quite work since it would depend on when the user decides to scroll.

Comment: you can use the newer MutationObserver events to monitor the adding of new content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @dandavis: Hey, that did the trick! I ended up using a JS library called 'Mutation Summary' (which is actually based off of Mutation Observer) and I figured out how to hook these so-called mutations! Thanks a bunch! (P.S. I'm not sure how to mark your comment as the answer...)

Comment: Post your MutationObserver answer at the duplicate question, it should get upvotes there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how an image is added when the window is scrolled:

```js
window.onscroll = myFunction;

function myFunction() {

  if (!document.getElementById('img1')) {
    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.id = 'img1';
    img1.src = 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300';
    document.body.appendChild(img1);
  }

}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```